# Does gRPC have the ability to add a maximum retry for call?

Tags: python, grpc

I haven't found any examples how to add a retry logic on some rpc call. Does gRPC have the ability to add a maximum retry for call? 
If so, is it a built-in function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retries are not a feature of gRPC Python at this time.

Comment: Thanks. I found external lib for retrying

Comment: Hi @creedqq, could you please share your findings

Comment: @Prakhar https://pypi.org/project/retrying/
Build-in retry mechanist currently on proposal stage:

Comment: This library also addresses the retry issue https://github.com/liut/grpc-retry-py